# Is the data in the bigquery table overwritten after being transferred from firebase?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, google-cloud-console

When transferring data from Firebase to bigquery to the events_ table, everyday we get data for the previous day in the morning. Is this the final data or will it still be overwritten, similar to Google analytics (overwriting data within 3 days before their final stabilization)?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on the [BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846):

> Within each dataset, a table is imported for each day of export. These tables have the format `"events_YYYYMMDD"`.
>
> Additionally, a table is imported for app events received throughout the current day. This table is named `“events_intraday_YYYYMMDD"` and it is populated in real-time as app events are collected.
>
> If you are using BigQuery sandbox, there is no intraday import of events, and additional limits apply. Upgrade from the sandbox if you want intraday imports.

So if you're querying the `events_YYYYMMDD` tables, they are only written once the data for a day is completed, but if you qyery `events_intraday_YYYYMMDD` the data is updated during the day.

Comment: Yes, I read about it. But in the "Details" section of the `events_*` table (not intraday), I see that the **creation date** is the next calendar day, but the **Last modified** date is usually 2 days after the created date. I didn't see this fact in the documentation, so I decided to ask

Comment: I added a screen of the "Details" section to the text of the question above for clarification